# Click then CTRL Click not working with selenium-java 2.39 + Firefox 26

Tags: selenium

I'm facing this issue since some days now but didn't manage to overcome it trying different ideas.
Problem description: I wanna select a line in a table (GWT CellTable), perform some actions (which are my application specific) on it and then unselect back the line.

The line never gets unselected.
I'm quite new to selenium And I don't know if someone else has run into same problem and if there is a workaround to it. Thanks in advance

Code:

```
@Test
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public void testClearEventCodes(){
    refreshBrowser();

    testWEHSearch();

    WebContext faresContext = rootContext.gotoId(Strings.WEH_FARES_TABLE);

    //INITIALLY HOT AND EVENT FARE
    assertTrue("Y N N N N".equals(faresContext.gotoTableCell(1, 15).getText()));
    assertTrue("CHINAYEAR".equals(faresContext.gotoTableCell(1, 16).getText()));
    checkColorCodes(new HashMap<String, String[]>(){
        {
            put(getFareKey("GMP", "PAR", "KE", "0004", "K001", "OW", "Public"), new String[]{"1", COLOR_CODE_HOT_AND_EVENT_FARE});
        }
    });

    faresContext.gotoTableRow(1).getElementWebContext(1).click();
    rootContext.gotoId(Strings.WEH_CLEAR_EVENT_CODES_BUTTON).click();

    faresContext.gotoTableRow(1).getElementWebContext(1).ctrlClick();

    //ENSURE ALL EVENT CODES ARE CLEARED
    assertTrue("".equals(faresContext.gotoTableCell(1, 16).getText()));
    checkColorCodes(new HashMap<String, String[]>(){
        {
            put(getFareKey("GMP", "PAR", "KE", "0004", "K001", "OW", "Public"), new String[]{"1", COLOR_CODE_HOT_FARE});
        }
    });
}
```

And bellow is the method to CTRL CLICK the line:

```
/**
 * Holds Control key and Clicks on current element.
 */
public void ctrlClick() {
    Actions actionBuilder = new Actions(driver);
    actionBuilder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(getSingleElement()).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);
    org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action action = actionBuilder.build();
    action.perform();
}
```

Comment: N.B: This is working fine in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be related to the new Firefox feature in which display settings are now taken into account. You can try changing the display settings for your computer to 100% and try again.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6774