# Relenium: how to select a checkbox?

Tags: r, selenium

I am experimenting with the R port of [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/), namely the recently released [Relenium](http://lluisramon.github.io/relenium/). Locating web elements on the page using Relenium seems straightforward enough so far. However, I am having difficulty selecting and deselecting checkboxes. Given the following code I would expect some change in the state of the checkbox on the web page:

```
library(relenium)
firefox <- firefoxClass$new()
firefox$get("http://jamaserv.jama.or.jp/newdb/eng/prod4/prod4TsMkEntry.html")
firefox$printHtml()

chkbox <- firefox$findElementByXPath("//input[@name='chkCarMaker4All'][@type='checkbox']")

chkbox$isSelected()
chkbox$click()
chkbox$isSelected()
```

What I get is this, which suggests that no change in state has been achieved:

```
chkbox$isSelected() # query checkbox state
[1] TRUE
> chkbox$click() # to deselect box
> chkbox$isSelected()
[1] TRUE # no change in state?
>
```

I have looked at questions related to using Selenium in other languages such as [this one for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682763/how-to-select-checkboxes-using-selenium-java-webdriver) but haven't applied them to my own case with any success. This is the first time I have used Selenium, so it may be that I am missing something obvious in its Relenium variant. Any pointers on how to select/deselect checkboxes would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is the result of some strange interaction between Firefox, Selenium and Windows 7.

If in your Windows 7 display settings the font is set to anything other than 100% then Selenium will *not* click on page elements. I had my fonts set to 125%. After resetting this to 100% I became able to set and unset checkboxes in Relenium, so it doesn't appear to be Relenium-specific after all.

The problem is mentioned in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837480/click-then-ctrl-click-not-working-with-selenium-java-2-39-firefox-26) and described in more detail and with a screenshot on [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6774) Selenium issue report page. Thanks to Relenium co-author [Lluis Ramon](https://github.com/LluisRamon/relenium) for finding this fix.